# Does avoiding Promises and Async leads to clean code?

Tags: javascript, async, promises

While applying for a job interview I found this line in requirements.

> Experience with clean code writing practices like avoiding callback hell like promises, async

Does this line make any sense ? If yes, can we actually stop using promises and async ?

Comment: Informal Commentary like this in a job description suggests that they are looking for someone who agrees with the idea that these are problems.

Comment: I think that line is just grammatically confusing. It probably wants to say that promises and async code are techniques to avoid callback hell, and that they would like you to be familiar with these techniques.

Comment: I believe they just forgot a word or two there: "Experience with clean code writing practices like avoiding callback hell (i.e. like using promises, async)".

Comment: @amon *Hopefully* wants to say

Answer (score -1):

Strange. I would decide whether I actually want to spend the time figuring out what they actually mean, or not. My decision would be "not". Words like "callback hell" point to dogmatism in their approach, and that's probably not an environment that I would enjoy. It may be that they just missed some words, but being so lazy / inconsiderate that they can't even get the words in their advert right, that's also a big red flag.

Comment: Yes, it sounds very childish. On the other hand, job ads often give you a completely wrong picture, because they are often written by people who won't have anything to do with your actual daily work if you get the job (especially in big companies).